# Query BaseX with xslt module error on [XPST0003] Expecting variable declaration

Tags: xslt, basex

I'm using xslt module to query BaseX.

```html
<query><text>
    let $xml := doc("/dsn_ext/pcbtestxmldbdata001_test001.xml") 
    let $style := <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" /><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet> 
    return xslt:transform-text($xml,$style)
</text>
</query>
```

I do the query on BaseX GUI and it works!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ujd.jpg)

BUT! When I do the same query on postman to query BaseX on remote server by api ,it fails!
The error messages are:
Stopped at /srv/basex/webapp, 3/19:
[XPST0003] Expecting variable declaration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7vPc.jpg)

I don't know why this error occured.Is there anybody could help me to solve this problem ?
Help!!!!!!!
My baseX versions on local and remote are both 9.5.0

I try it on BaseXGUI and it works correctly
but when I try it on postman then it fails!
I hope the query will work correctly on postman !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you show of the BaseX GUI actually shows the query

```
let $xml := doc("/dsn_ext/pcbtestxmldbdata001_test001.xml") 
    let $style := <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" /><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet> 
    return xslt:transform-text($xml,$style)
```

(no wrapping `<query><text>`), which is a valid query.

I don't know Postman but I would expect that it wants the query to be the string value of the `<text>` element. To achieve that you will need to escape the contained elements, typically by wrapping them in a CDATA section:

```
<query><text><![CDATA[
    let $xml := doc("/dsn_ext/pcbtestxmldbdata001_test001.xml") 
    let $style := <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" /><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet> 
    return xslt:transform-text($xml,$style)
]]></text>
</query>
```